# How can make sure my app Module will be always available to Google Search Console (AngualrJS app)

Tags: seo, google-search-console, javascript, angular.js

I'm trying to test some of my web pages on Google Search Console.
Some of the times i can see the content of the page i look for (but without the dynamic HTML), and sometimes I'm getting errors like - 

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.`

I think this problem occurs because some of the times the html gets loaded before all the scripts are imported (I'm just assuming.)
So I was thinking to create some function that will force the html to wait one more second before it gets rendered (just to make sure) bit I couldn't manage to do it.
Is it possible to do it, and will it even help google to test the page successfully?
Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: If you need SEO, I would recommend switching to a non-JavaScript based framework.   Angular and React are really hard to get working with Google.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option.